# Wrapping pyspark Pipeline.__init__ and decorators

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to wrap the constructor for pyspark Pipeline.**init** constructor, and monkey patch in the newly wrapped constructor. However, I am running into an error that seems to have something to do with the way Pipeline.**init** uses decorators

Here is the code that actually does the monkey patch:

```
    def monkeyPatchPipeline():
      oldInit = Pipeline.__init__

      def newInit(self, **keywordArgs):
        oldInit(self, stages=keywordArgs["stages"])

      Pipeline.__init__ = newInit
```

However, when I run a simple program:

```
import PythonSparkCombinatorLibrary
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer

PythonSparkCombinatorLibrary.TransformWrapper.monkeyPatchPipeline()
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(),outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.001)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, lr])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<my path>\PythonApplication1\main.py", line 26, in <module>
   pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, lr])
  File "C:<my path>PythonApplication1 \PythonSparkCombinatorLibrary.py", line 36, in newInit
oldInit(self, stages=keywordArgs["stages"])
  File "C:\<pyspark_path>\pyspark\__init__.py", line 98, in wrapper
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\<pyspark_path>\pyspark\ml\pipeline.py", line 63, in __init__
    kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_input_kwargs'
```

Looking into the pyspark interface, I see that  Pipeline.**init** looks like this:

```
@keyword_only
def __init__(self, stages=None):
    """
    __init__(self, stages=None)
    """
    if stages is None:
        stages = []
    super(Pipeline, self).__init__()
    kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
    self.setParams(**kwargs)
```

And noting the @keyword_only decorator, I inspected that code as well:

```
def keyword_only(func):
    """
    A decorator that forces keyword arguments in the wrapped method
    and saves actual input keyword arguments in `_input_kwargs`.
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 1:
            raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
        wrapper._input_kwargs = kwargs
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I'm totally confused both about how this code works in the first place, and also why it seems to cause problems with my own wrapper. I see that wrapper is adding a _input_kwargs field to itself, but how is Pipeline.__init__ about to read that field with self.__init__._input_kwargs?  And why doesn't the same thing happen when I wrap Pipeline.__init__ again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator 101. Decorator is a higher-order function which takes a function as its first argument (and typically only), and returns a function. `@` annotation is just a syntactic sugar for a simple function call, so following

```
@decorator
def decorated(x):
    ...
```

can be rewritten for example as:

```
def decorated_(x):
    ...

decorated  = decorator(decorated_)
```

So `Pipeline.__init__` is actually a [`functools.wrapped`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) `wrapper` which captures defined `__init__` (`func` argument of the `keyword_only`) as a part of its closure. When it is called, it uses received `kwargs` as a [function attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) of itself. Basically what happens here can be simplified to:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    f._input_kwargs = kwargs  # f is in the current scope

hasattr(f, "_input_kwargs")
```

```
False
```

```py
f(foo=1, bar="x")

hasattr(f, "_input_kwargs")
```

```
True
```

When you further wrap (decorate) `__init__` the external function won't have `_input_kwargs` attached, hence the error. If you want to make it work you have apply the same process, as used by the original `__init__`, to your own version, for example with the same decorator:

```
@keyword_only
def newInit(self, **keywordArgs):
    oldInit(self, stages=keywordArgs["stages"])
```

but I liked I mentioned in the comments, you should rather consider subclassing.