# Custom algorithm in Pyspark MLlib: 'function' object has no attribute '_input_kwargs'

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to roll my own MLlib Pipeline algorithm in Pyspark but I can't get past the following error:

```
'function' object has no attribute '_input_kwargs'
```

I've reduced my code right down to this:

```
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml.param import Params

class SimpleAlgorithm(Params):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, threshold=2.0):

        super(SimpleAlgorithm, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, threshold=2.0):

        kwargs = self.setParams._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)
```

but when I do this:

```
test_alg = SimpleAlgorithm()
```

I get the error shown above. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong please? (I saw an apparently related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833296/wrapping-pyspark-pipeline-init-and-decorators) but, as a Python newbie, I'm not sure I understood the answer or whether it was relevant to me.)

**EDIT** In case it helps here is the full stacktrace of the error after running it on a Spark 2.1 Databricks cluster:

```
----> 1 test_alg = SimpleAlgorithm()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     99             raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
    100         self._input_kwargs = kwargs
--> 101         return func(self, **kwargs)
    102     return wrapper
    103 

<ipython-input-12-dcb888c97487> in __init__(self, threshold)
      8 
      9         #super(SimpleAlgorithm, self).__init__()
---> 10         kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
     11         self.setParams(**kwargs)
     12 

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_input_kwargs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
```

You are trying to access the attribute `_input_kwargs` on the `function` object `self.__init__`, which doesn't exist.

If you are just trying to set the `threshold` attribute, I would typically just do:

```
class SimpleAlgorithm(Params):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, threshold=2.0):
        super(SimpleAlgorithm, self).__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold
```

### EDIT:

I checked the source you linked, and noticed that the implementation of the `keyword_only` wrapper changed from Spark 2.1 to Spark 2.2. Your code should indeed work for Spark 2.1, but if you are using Spark 2.2 you should replace it with:

```
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml.param import Params

class SimpleAlgorithm(Params):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, threshold=2.0):

        super(SimpleAlgorithm, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, threshold=2.0):

        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)
```

[Link to v2.2 `keyword_only` implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/python/pyspark/__init__.py#L92)

[Link to v2.2 example usage](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/python/pyspark/ml/classification.py#L134)

Comment: Thanks. I will probably do what you suggest in the end but I was hoping someone with specific knowledge of the MLlib code would respond. Because it's the `@keyword_only` decorator that's supposed to be creating `_input_args`; see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/python/pyspark/__init__.py#L98 . Plus I'm trying to follow the pattern used by other PySpark algorithms ([here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/python/pyspark/ml/classification.py#L1403) for example), so I don't understand why my code (simplified here) doesn't work whereas theirs does.

Comment: @snark Ah, I see. I've updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks @timchap! Good spot! Looks like the code change was made between Spark 2.1.0 and 2.1.1 in [SPARK-19438](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19348). The Databricks cluster's using 2.1.1 so your code changes work. Strangely, they also seem to work on another cluster I'm using, which is running Spark 2.1.0. Not sure why, but I'll go with that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is some more information on the changes to `keyword_only` between 2.1.0 and 2.1.1: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/44281ca81d4eda02b627ba21841108438b7d1c27

Answer (score 1):

I want to contribute to @timchap  answer. If you are working on `Zeppelin 0.7.3` which uses `Spark 2.1.0` but your code runs on spark `2.2.0` you could check the version and pick up the compatible version this way

```
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml.param import Params

class SimpleAlgorithm(Params):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, threshold=2.0):

        super(SimpleAlgorithm, self).__init__()
        if spark.version.startswith('2.1'):
            kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        else:
            kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, threshold=2.0):

        if spark.version.startswith('2.1'):
            kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        else:
            kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)
```